# How can I set a direction for table's cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container{
  background-color: #e0eaf1;
  width: 160px;
}

.author a, .editor a{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.author b, .editor b{
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="share_edit_flag">
    <span>share</span>
    <span>edit</span>
    <span>delete</span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
        <b>12.6k</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="author">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
        <b>1</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set `.container` boxes to the right side of the table's cell. How can I do that?

When I set `float: right` to `.container`, it also affects on `.share_edit_flag` element and makes it broken.

Comment: `text-align:right`

Comment: use css flexbox

Comment: @zer00ne [won't work](https://jsfiddle.net/f7ymg3Lj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to familiarize with `flexbox`, which is great for avoiding things like `float`.

That being said, your issue with `float` most-likely is that you weren't clearing them after. If you want the text *within* the container to appear to the right, then you'll also need to add `text-align: right;` to the `.container`.

I've added a `container::after` rule that will automatically clear them. See if this works for you:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container{
  background-color: #e0eaf1;
  width: 160px;
  float: right;
}

.container::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.author a, .editor a{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.author b, .editor b{
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="share_edit_flag">
    <span>share</span>
    <span>edit</span>
    <span>delete</span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
        <b>12.6k</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="author">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
        <b>1</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well in your case, still `share edit delete` are in the bottom of box. They should be in the top.

Comment: Check my edit. I've added `vertical-align: top;` to keep the text aligned properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .table {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .table > div {
      display: table-cell;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .container{
      background-color: #e0eaf1;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .author a, .editor a{
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .author b, .editor b{
      font-size: 12px;
    }
```